# Reutilizar una sola vista en varios items del Navigation drawer con Androidx

Tags: android, navigationview, navigation, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

Actualmente el componente de navegación de Androidx por defecto vincula un item del navigationView, con un fragmento del gráfico de navegación.
Pero lo que deseo hacer es reutilizar un solo fragmento para la todos o la mayoría de items.
Esto se puede lograr a la antigua con el "onNavigationItemSelected", pero no se si exista una forma mas pro de hacerlo utilizando el componente de navegación de Androidx

Comment: Hola una consulta, cual es el problema si agregas el mismo fragment en el gráfico de navegación?

Comment: Cual es el código que estas realizando, revisa [ask], agrega lo que investigaste o trataste por favor , saludos.

Comment: Gracias @rguzman ! Dias intentando y no se como no se me pudo haber ocurrido eso. Simplemente en el grafico de navegacion agregar destinos PLACEHOLDER, y luego en "name" le colocas la referencia al fragment!